# SSRS Set up the datasource to NOT require the end user to enter credential information for a report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am fairly new to SQL Server Reporting.  I am using SQL server 2008, running on a server using server 2008 standard and Business Studio to create the reports.  I have built my report which can be accessed via a button on my secure (ssl) website and it all works great.

However, I have yet to find a way to eliminate the need for the credentials to be entered once each day (plus the first time each takes like 60 seconds).

I have tried various methods including using dsu, dsp parameter in the URL but no luck.  I get the sense that because I am using windows Authentication, even thought it says "integrated security", I have to do something else.

If I try to assign user name and password, it is apparently looking for something else than windows credentials.

Because the people who come to my web site are already using secured logins, I don't want them to have to do anything other than hit the button to display their reports.

Can someone point me to "clear" instructions on how best to set this part up?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The connection string is part of the Datasource. You have to set it so it won't ask you for the credentials over and over...

To change it, go to the data tab on your report, click on the DataSet, click to edit the DataSource, click on Edit. Enter your user name and password below "Use SQL Server Authentication", select "Save My Password". Ok. Ok.

That should save your password.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save user name and password in the datasource definition that are defined on the underlying database. That is you can create a read-only database login and use that.